# How can I stream data through odata?

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I currently have a route that returns archived by date data stored in protobuf files. 
Currently, I use a `PushStreamContent` to write the result back in json. Here is what I currently do::

```
[HttpGet,Route(...)]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage>(
    string asset, 
    DateTime archiveDate, 
    CancellationToken token
){
    var archivedData = await _archiveService.GetArchivedData(asset,archiveDate,token);
    if(archivedData == null){
        return await NotFound().ExecuteAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var res = ConvertToWire(asset,archivedData);
    var typeFormatter = Configuration.Formatters.First();

    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, transport) =>
        {
            using (var outerStream = new BufferedStream(stream, 8*1024))
            {
                await typeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(res.GetType(), res, outerStream,
                    content, transport, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            stream.Close();
        }, JsonUtf8);
    return response;
  };
```

ConvertToWire basically knows about the assets we support, and applies a wire format and returns that as `IEnumerable<T>`. I can make this return `IQueryable<T>` fairly easily (`res.ToQueryable()`). With this approach I can stream the data out of the files quite easily. 
How can I add support for Odata, while still maintaining the ability to stream the result set. Some of the assets have very large filesizes (50+ mb) so streaming is required.

Comment: I've hit this same problem, since OData requires an ObjectContent based result I don't think it's possible. 
Kinda stupid asking us to choose between async streaming our result or querying our endpoint though don't you think?
Feels like a design flaw to me.

Comment: Looks like this is still sat waiting https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/622

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Anybody found a solution?